# Word 2007: keyboard shortcut to autocorrect a word in front of the cursor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2007, autocorrect

Is there a way to make a keyboard shortcut in Word 2007 that autocorrects the word directly in front of the cursor? Much like the autocorrect feature on mobile devices. It should automatically accept the top suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following macro to achieve this and bind it to a keyboard combination of your choice.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Selection.GoToNext(wdGoToSpellingError)

With r.GetSpellingSuggestions()
  If .Count > 0 Then
    r.Text = .Item(1).Name
  End If
End With
```

Comment: I am going to try this when I have the time :)